# Can I use the Google Drive API with firebase auth for Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-drive-api

I am developing an application to access a user's Google Drive files after signing them in. I have integrated Firebase Auth API for signing users in and am trying to integrate the Google Drive API for accessing files and folders.

- When I try to create OAuth credentials, the developer console says 'This Android package is already in use somewhere else' or something to that effect. My guess is it is referring to the firebase project already created.

I read through some of the other questions and it seems I might need to delete the firebase project and create credentials with only Google developer console.

Is there a workaround? Any other ways to do this?

Comment: Are you using the old firebase authentication or the updated Google Cloud Authentication for Firebase?

Comment: Whats the old firebase authentication @RafaelZasas? Though I think that might be the issue. LEt me try that out. Can you provide a link to some documentation?

Comment: Here is a link to the (Firebase Auth Docs)[https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth#identity-platform] where they reference the usage of Firebase Auth with the Identity Platform. You should also see a notification in the Firebase Console prompting you to switch to the Identity Platform Authentication